# Why "Email clicked" And "Email opened" activity types are not shown in Marketing actions tab in sitecore 9.0.1?

Tags: marketing-automation

There are two Activity types named **Email clicked** and **Email opened** in Marketing Automation.

But both of these items are not loaded in the `Marketing Automation` Tab.

Why?

[image]

Comment: We haven't implemented them yet ;)

Comment: @JacobNielsen - Will this be implemented in Sitecore 9 Update 2?

Answer (score 1):

As of Sitecore 10.1, these two Activity types named **Email clicked** and **Email opened** have not been implemented, though you can see these activity types items created in Sitecore at the path `/Sitecore/system/Settings/Analytics/Marketing Automation/Activity Types`

[image]

but seems like functionality for these activities is not yet written in the Angular plugin. Hence these activities are not visible in Sitecore Marketing Automation.

[image]

If you want to evaluate a contact based on email opened or email clicked, you can utilize **Custom Listener** or **Decision Point** element and using the rule editor, apply email click or open rules:

[image]
[image]